# Connecting multiple sensors, servos, etc. to Raspberry Pi 4 B

Tags: gpio, i2c, connection

### Hello everyone

I recently got a bunch of sensors, servos, transmitters, etc. (like literally I have now a hundred of different sensors)
But now, how to connect it all to Raspberry Pi (in my case ver. 4B) and take control over all of them?

### My questions are: ❓

1. How to extend number of GPIO pins on Raspberry Pi? - If yes, what should I by to get more GPIO pins? By default there are 26 GPIO pins, but can I have like a 150 GPIO pins or something on one Raspberry Pi? Does it require any additional libraries if extending in that way is possible?
2. How to connect multiple devices to I2C? - I saw some hubs for that, but I don't understand how it works and how to start. If someone would provide a simple explanation I would be thankful. Also, does it require any additional libraries?
3. Are there limitations for connecting like a hundred sensors to Raspberry Pi over GPIO / I2C or not?

If you have any examples for solutions of mentioned problems, I will be grateful for sending it

Comment: I am surprised your research hasn't found any answers.  What are you using as search terms?

Comment: Do you have a project requiring hundreds of sensors? If so ask about it.

Comment: I haven't found any simple explanation for my questions. Yes, I can search in google pretty well, because I code most of my time as a backend developer.

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome. *"But now, how to connect it all to Raspberry Pi "* -> One at a time. How many have you tried so far?

Comment: start with one sensor